# Postgresql : set timestamp to null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have searched across SO related questions, but I couldn't find the solution for :

How to set timestamp to NULL during an insert to DB or an update ? (in postgresql).

If I put NULL like `pstat.setTimestamp(idx++, null);` I get an error which says that the type I put in is integer and that I should cast to Timestamp.

As definition for this table column, I use : `ADD COLUMN admin_validation_date timestamp with time zone`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pstat.setNull(idx++, Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

should do it.